# How can I easily backup multiple folders on EC2 to S3

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, amazon-s3

I move dockers around a lot on EC2 instances. Each docker has a specific folder on the host where it stores it's data.

I want to create a single backup script that will look for any of a list of possible folders and back each up to a file on S3 whose name is date stamped by day of month. So you end up with one month's worth of backups.

I want the backup script to gzip and stream the data to S3 to save on local disk space and IO.

Assume the S3 command line tools are installed and configured.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please help us in helping you by telling us more about what you've tried and your thoughts on why it didn't work. http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# List folders here that may or may not be under base path.
# If folder isn't under base path we do nothing.
# If it exists we back it up to S3.
# S3 file is stamped to day of month.
# So you have a months worth of backups.
declare -a folders=(
  "elasticsearch"
  "jenkins"
  "some-cool-app"
)

BASE_PATH="/home/ubuntu/"
BUCKET="my.cool.bucket"

for FOLDER in "${folders[@]}"
do
  test -d ${BASE_PATH}${FOLDER}  && \
    tar -cz -C ${BASE_PATH} ${FOLDER} \
    | aws s3 cp - s3://${BUCKET}/${FOLDER}-$(date '+%d').tgz
done
```

Comment: btw you need a very recent version of aws command line tools.